# Connect to SQL server from self made module

Tags: python, sql-server, module

I currently have many scripts that connect to the same MSSQL database. I make the connection in each of the scripts, but for ease of use I want to put the connection in a module and call that module from my script. The code in my module connect_to_db.pyc looks like this:

```
import pyodbc

def sql_connect():
    server="some_server.net"
    port="1433"
    user = "my_username@my_domain"
    server="my_server"
    database="my_database"
    conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=my_server,1433', 
    user=user, 
    password=password, 
    database=database) 
    c=conn.cursor()
```

Then, in my script I try to call this module and run a query:

```
from connect_to_db import sql_connect

sql_connect()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
```

I get the error that the name c is not defined. I tried to define it as a global too, but it don't help. It must have something to do with my lack of understanding modules, but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return cursor in your sql_connect function

```
 import pyodbc

def sql_connect():
     server="some_server.net"
     port="1433"
     user = "my_username@my_domain"
     server="my_server"
     database="my_database"
     conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=my_server,1433', 
     user=user, 
     password=password, 
     database=database) 
     return conn.cursor()
```

And then you can use it as

from connect_to_db import sql_connect

```
c = sql_connect()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed missing a bit there:

in your function `sql_connect`, you assign to a local variable named `c`.

That variable is not existant outside your function.
If you want a connection variable to exist on module level, maybe try the following attempt:

In your "connect_to_db.py":

```
import pyodbc

def sql_connect():
    server="some_server.net"
    port="1433"
    user = "my_username@my_domain"
    server="my_server"
    database="my_database"
    conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=my_server,1433', 
    user=user, 
    password=password, 
    database=database) 
    return conn.cursor()

cursor = sql_connect()
```

This creates a varibale "cursor" on the level of the module.
In another module, simply perform

```
from connect_to_db import cursor
```

to import the module's "cursor" member.

This should do the trick.

**Hint:** Please be advised that this approach may not be very elegant, in terms of software-engineering.

**Edit:**

Maybe, you may want to dive deeper into object-oriented programming?

```
class MSSQLConnector(object):

    def __init__(self, server, port, database, user, password):
        self.server = server
        self.port = port
        self.conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='{0},
            {1}.format((self.server, self.port)), user, password, database)
    def open_cursor(self):
        return self.conn.cursor()
```

Which would be used in this fashion:

```
connector = MSSQLConnector("my_server", "1433", "my_database", "username", "secret-password")
cursor = connector.open_cursor()
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! In terms of elegance, would you recommend the approach of tomasmor? Or are there even nicer ways to build this?

Comment: In terrms of elegance, @tomasmor provided a much cleaner solution. Having a cursor instantiated on module level is a bit "magic", which should, in general, be avoided. Also, have a look at resource guards in python, which will even facilitate closing and error-checking when resources go out of scope.

Comment: Thanks! I was afraid you were going to bring up object-oriented programming... I have been able to put my head in the sand for quite some time, but I think my time has come...